# Yii2 how change loginUrl in components user for module

Tags: php, yii2

I have following config a component `user`

```
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\web\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'loginUrl'=>['/backend/login'],
    ],
```

I have 2 modules `backend` and `frontend`. I want if user go to the backend part  need use following rule `'loginUrl'=>['/backend/login']` and if to thefrontend part this rule `'loginUrl'=>['/frontend/login']`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

For any module or controller you can redirect to your login action using AccessControl behavior in module or controller:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
            'denyCallback' => function($rule, $action) {
                return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['/your/login/url']);
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

Or in Module class file:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = ['/your/login/url'];
}
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answers, solid solution when using basic template with two or more modules with separate login, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use an advanced template you have two configuration files

```
 backend / config / main.php
 frontend / config / main.php
```

separated.
You can configure the appropriate urlLogin separately.